# R X&Y axes interval setup in histogram

Tags: r, intervals

I have been using the following code. But, instead of starting at -5000, the x-axis is starting at 0. Also, I would like to specify an interval of 100 for both x and y-axes ranges. I tried to use `xaxt='n'` and `axis(side=1)`, but that didn't help. The following code is the one I am currently working on

```
setwd("/path/")
data<-read.table("input.txt",sep="\t",header=F)
x<-data$V4
h<-hist(x, col="green",xlim=c(-5000, 162000),ylim=c(0,0.0003),main="TPMDistribution",xlab="TPMValues",probability=TRUE)
s=sd(x)
m=mean(x)
curve(dnorm(x,mean=m,sd=s),add=TRUE,lwd=3,col="red")
lines(density(x),col="blue")
abline(v=mean(x),col="blue")
mtext(paste("mean",round(mean(x),1),";sd",round(sd(x),1),";N",length(x),sep=""),side=1,cex=.75)
dev.off()
```

All helps appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify the breaks, probably in an array, see here:
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/hist.html

And adjust the axis using something like this:
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/axis.html

You may need to use axes=FALSE in your hist(), so you can replace them with axis() in a subsequent line.

Comment: Hi, I tried the following

    `h<-hist(x, axes=FALSE, xaxt='n', yaxt='n',col="green",main="GATA3-TPMDistribution",xlab="TPMValues",probability=TRUE)
    axis (side=1, at=seq(-162000,162000, 1))
    axis (side=2, at=seq(0,0.008,0.000001))`

I am getting the histogram with the negative co-ordinates. But, the curve's start point and the peak are getting truncated. Any thoughts on why this is happening?